# How do I get this layout in my titanium app?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

This is a common layout for having multiple layouts vertically aligned and I can't figure out how to obtain it in my app:

[image: Layout I would like to acheive]

I have figured out how to do this:

[image]

But I really like the way the rounded corners look at the top and bottom of the group looks. I know you can achieve rounded corners with

```
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
   borderRadius:10,
   backgroundColor:'red',
   width:50,
   height:50
});
window.add(view);
```

but I would really like it to look like the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Appcelerator Kitchen Sink project has an example or 2 of this.

Here is one:
https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/baseui/table_views.js

Answer (score 1):

Please refer [Join Two Text Fields](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140215/join-two-text-fields#243878), which helped me to create text fields with rounded corner.

You can download the images from the following links

1. [Rounded top](http://iampnelson.com/tmp/TableViewRoundedTop.png)
2. [Middle Image](http://iampnelson.com/tmp/TableViewMiddle.png)
3. [Rounded Bottom](http://iampnelson.com/tmp/TableViewRoundedBottom.png)